# r ggplot contours density

Tags: r, ggplot2

Was going through an iris example on ggplot and received error message listed below, wondering why adjusting alpha will not resolve.

```r
library (datasets)
# Scatterplot, colored by species, fit line, density

    ggplot(iris, 
      aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length,
        color = Species)) +
      geom_point(size = 3) +
      geom_smooth(method = lm) +
      geom_density2d(alpha = .5) +

  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

```
geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Warning messages:
1: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated 
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: I think the problem is that setosa is much denser than the other species, and forces the contours too far apart for the other species to register at all.  You can get round this by adjusting the number of contours with, e.g. `bins = 50` in the `geom_density2d(...)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get bin sizes to works, so after a little research I found the contour_var option.

```
geom_density2d(alpha=0.5, contour_var = "ndensity")
```

This did the trick, and gets the expected result for the IRIS dataset (as per the training that I was following :-)